# NullPointerException in SpringBoot - Hibernate mapping while inserting data through postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

Here is the Entity's:

```
public class ProductOffer extends AuditModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id = null;
    
    @Column(name = "offer_code", nullable = false)
    private String offerCode = null;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String version = null;

    @Column
    private String offerCodeVersion = null;

    @Column
    private String offerName = null;

    @Column
    private String description = null;

    @Column
    private String status = null;

    @JsonProperty
    private OperationEnum operation;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lifecycleStatus_id", referencedColumnName = "lId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private LifeCycleStatus lifecycleStatus = null;
}

public class LifeCycleStatus extends AuditModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer lId = null;

    @Column
    private String name = null;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "lifecycleStatus", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProductOffer> productOffer = new ArrayList<ProductOffer>();
}
```

Herer  is the DAO:

```
public void addProductOffer(ProductOffer productOffer) {

        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        LifeCycleStatus lifeCycleStatus = lifeCycleStatusDAO.findById(productOffer.getLifecycleStatus().getLId()); /* am getting NPE here */
        if(lifeCycleStatus == null)
            lifeCycleStatus = new LifeCycleStatus();
        lifeCycleStatus.setName(productOffer.getLifecycleStatus().getName());
        productOffer.setLifecycleStatus(lifeCycleStatus);
        session.saveOrUpdate(productOffer);
    }
```

Here is the Post mapping details:

```
{

   "offerCode":"HG123",
   "version":"2",
   "offerCodeVersion":"2.2",
   "offerName":"Recharge",
   "description":"aadhakjdhaks",
   "status":"Inactive",
   "operation":"PUBLISH",
   "lifecycleStatus":{
       "lId":2,
       "name":"InActive"
   }
}
```

Here is the complete error log

> 2020-07-21 18:55:42 - o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] -
>
> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> com.hima.demo.dao.ProductOfferDAO.addProductOffer(ProductOfferDAO.java:34)
> at
> com.hima.demo.dao.ProductOfferDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2cf28c6a.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
> at
> com.hima.demo.dao.ProductOfferDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52838a30.addProductOffer()
> at
> com.hima.demo.services.ProductOfferService.addProductOffer(ProductOfferService.java:26)
> at
> com.hima.demo.services.ProductOfferService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$92d2ad77.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
> at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
> at
> com.hima.demo.services.ProductOfferService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3ba67d77.addProductOffer()
> at
> com.hima.demo.controller.ProductOfferController.createProductOffer(ProductOfferController.java:35)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Can any one please help me on this?

I have referred to many articles but no use please help me. I am not getting an idea where am missing..

Comment: can you provide some way to recreate the error,

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line `@JsonIgnore
private LifeCycleStatus lifecycleStatus = null;` ?

Comment: Which line is line 34 in `DAO` ?

Comment: Here is the line 34: LifeCycleStatus lifeCycleStatus = lifeCycleStatusDAO.findById(productOffer.getLifecycleStatus().getLId()); /* am getting NPE here */

Comment: i.e ManyToOne Mapping @JsonIgnore private LifeCycleStatus lifecycleStatus = null;--> We have different status of the producoffer. so trying to mapping with status and update the status u may look into LifeCycleStatus Entity class. this is bi-directional mapping

Answer (score 0):

I know it's silly, but can you rename `lId` to `lid` (capital 'I' to small 'i')??

variable name `lid` with all small latter and do relevant changes in all other files as well in DAO and then try again!

also from postman send request with "lid" (all small latter)